# Как сделать, чтобы элемент TabControl растягивался вместе с окном

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

У меня внутри элемента `Grid` есть элемент `TabControl`.

Как сделать, чтобы при расширении окна приложения расширялся и этот элемент?

В свойствах элемента в разделе "Макет" есть поля `Width` и `Height`, они установлены в `Auto`, но я еще не разобрался, как они работают.

[image]

**Добавил код (второй раз):**

Каким-то чудом теперь выравнивается по верхнему левому краю и растягивается по горизонтали, а по вертикали не хочет растягиваться

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <TabControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="tabControl" Height="315" Margin="118,0,0,0">
        <TabItem Header="Terminal" BorderThickness="0">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,6,0,-1">
                <TextBlock>Terminal</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Mail" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <TextBlock>Mail</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Network" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <TextBlock>Network</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: TabControl у вас внутри StackPanel, а не Grid. StackPanel не расширяется на все доступное пространство.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для выравнивания другие свойства:

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Но, вроде, это и так значения по умолчанию. Вы б код привели, а не картинку. Не исключено, что какой-то элемент управления в промежутке мешает растягиваться.

**[Правка]**

Уберите `StackPanel`, панель здесь лишняя.